# Apache web server is not Restarting? with php?

Tags: php, windows-7, apache2, installation

i was installed the Apche webserver sucessfully.it works fine when i run the local host in the browse.

But i am putting the # 
LoadModule php5_module "D:/php/php5apache2.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

## configure the path to php.ini

PHPIniDir "D:/php"

in configuration file .The request is failed whenever i restart the server

Thanks in Adavnce please help me to overcome that issue

Comment: Whay does it say in the error log file?

Comment: when i save the one php file to server and i restarted it shows the message The requested operation is failed?

Comment: You dot need to restart your server. Just put the PHP file in the document root directory (or sub directory). It sounds like you have a bug in your PHP file. When you say that it has failed, what is the error message (perhaps view page source)

Comment: http://localhost/sample.php when i am giving like this the notepad text is displayed.it canot show the php generated optpit?

Comment: without that script how can i give the php path to webserver?

Answer (score 0):

You need the following in your apache configuration file (with the appropriate paths).

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "c:/Program Files/PHP"
```

You just put the `sample.php` in the appropriate place depending on your apache configuration.

Comment: when i putting this php related stuff in configuration file it canot restart?

Comment: without restart when  i run the sample.php it gives <?php
echo '<p>This is a PHP script</p>';
?> this is the code in the php file?

Comment: @user1300414 - put the above in your apache config (httpd.conf). restart. Then sample.php should work